# Passing the UserID to a SelectCommand in DotNetNuke

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I am trying to get the users who belong in a specific user role. Under /Admin/SecurityRoles.aspx after clicking 
on a specific role it shows the "FullName" of the users instead of the "Username" as the label says (DNN 6.2.9).

Therefore, without having to compile the code, I'm trying to get the UserID to pass it to a query in the ascx control. However I can't get the UserID from anywhere on the page. Any ideas?

```
  <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="User Name Test">
         <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="UsernameData" 
                       ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sitesqlserver %>" 
                       ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                       SelectCommand="select top 1 Username from dbo.Users where UserID =@UserID ">
                   <SelectParameters><asp:Parameter Name="UserID"  DefaultValue="xxx" /></SelectParameters>
               </asp:SqlDataSource>
               <asp:Listbox id="Labelxx" runat="server" 
                 DataTextField="Username" 
                 DataSourceID="UsernameData"></asp:Listbox>
          </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use tokens as listed in this page:

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/tokens

put this in

[User:UserID]

instead of this: @UserID

This is untested, so let me know if it works.